# Understanding the contents of the Makevars file in R (macros, variables, ~/.R/Makevars and pkg/src/Makevars)

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to understand the role and relationship of the macros/variables set in `~/.R/Makevars` and `package_directory/src/Makevars` when installing/building own R packages. Suppose these files look like

~/.R/Makevars

```
CXX = g++
CXXSTD = -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -fsanitize=undefined,address -fno-omit-frame-pointer

CXX98 = g++
CXX98STD = -std=c++98

CXX11 = g++
CXX11STD = -std=c++11

CXX14 = g++
CXX14STD = -std=c++14
```

package_directory/src/Makevars

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

As I understand it, with `CXX` we can select the compiler for C++ when building R packages, with `CXXSTD` we chose the standard and with `CXXFLAGS` we add compiler flags. With `PKG_CPPFLAGS` we add flags for the C++ preprocessor and with `CXX_STD` we tell that our packages uses C++11.

I have the following questions:

- What is the relationship between `CXX` and `CXX98`, `CXX11` and `CXX14`?
- What is the meaning of, e.g., `CXX11STD = -std=c++11` if C++11 is already implied? Is it between choosing `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11`? Should `-std=gnu++11` generally be avoided for portability reasons?
- Could the flags for `CXXSTD` and `CXXFLAGS` not just be added to `CXX`, such that the first three lines reduce to `CXX = g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=undefined,address -fno-omit-frame-pointer`. What is the advantage in explicity specifying `CXXSTD` and `CXXFLAGS`?
- How does `CXX_STD = CXX11` work? How is `CXX11` here related to `CXX11` in `~/.R/Makevars`?
- What is the relationship between `CXXFLAGS` and `PKG_CXXFLAGS`(not included in my example)?

I am aware of the information contained in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) and [R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Customizing-package-compilation), but I am not able to extract more information beyond my current level of understanding to answer the above questions.

I am adding a `Rcpp` tag because I suppose that answers to these questions will be most relevant to users of `Rcpp`, but I am aware that this is probably not directly related to `Rcpp`, so the tag might be removed if deemed appropriate.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The `Makevars` file, as specified in [Writing R Extensions: 1.2.1 Using Makevars](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars), is a variant of [`Make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) that is *unique* to R. Many of the variables you have listed are called [implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Implicit). The meaning is given as:

> Implicit rules tell make how to use customary techniques so that you do not have to specify them in detail when you want to use them.

These [implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) 
dictate *what* compiler should be used and *what* options are available.

Within *R*, we care about the following default compiler options:

> **CC** Program for compiling C programs; default ‘cc’.
>
> **CXX** Program for compiling C++ programs; default ‘g++’.
>
> **CPP** Program for running the C preprocessor, with results to standard output; default ‘$(CC) -E’.
>
> **FC** Program for compiling or preprocessing Fortran and Ratfor programs; default ‘f77’.

The next set of values details *what* options should be used by the compiler. In general, the default values for all of these options is an empty string.

> **CFLAGS** Extra flags to give to the C compiler.
>
> **CXXFLAGS** Extra flags to give to the C++ compiler.
>
> **CPPFLAGS** Extra flags to give to the C preprocessor and programs that use it (the C and Fortran compilers).
>
> **FFLAGS** Extra flags to give to the Fortran compiler.
>
> **LDFLAGS** Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’, such as -L. Libraries (-lfoo) should be added
>   to the LDLIBS variable instead.
>
> **LDLIBS** Library flags or names given to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’. LOADLIBES is a deprecated (but
>   still supported) alternative to LDLIBS. Non-library linker flags, such
>   as -L, should go in the LDFLAGS variable.

Now, *R* defines "extra" variants in terms of different C++ ISO standards. These variants are given in the [R Administration: Section 2.7.2 C++ Support](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#C_002b_002b-Support) and [R Administration: Section B.7 Compile and load flags](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Compile-and-load-flags)

> CXX98
>   CXX98STD
>   CXX98FLAGS 
>   CXX98PICFLAGS
>
> CXX11 
>   CXX11STD
>   CXX11FLAGS
>   CXX11PICFLAGS
>
> CXX14
>   CXX14STD
>   CXX14FLAGS 
>   CXX14PICFLAGS
>
> CXX17 
>   CXX17STD
>   CXX17FLAGS 
>   CXX17PICFLAGS

---

Having said this, let's tackle the first question:

> What is the relationship between `CXX` and `CXX98`, `CXX11` and `CXX14`?

`CXX` is the general compiler option to use. Meanwhile, *R* defines additional `CXX` options to use depending on the detected compilation standard. That is, if  `-std=c++98` (`CXX98` language spec) set by `CXX_STD`, then the compiler associated with `CXX98` is used. Similarly, for `CXX11` and `CXX14`, the same logic follows. See [Rcpp Gallery: Using Rcpp with C++11, C++14 and C++17](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-and-c++11-c++14-c++17/) for more details.

---

> What is the meaning of, e.g., `CXX11STD = -std=c++11` if C++11 is already implied? Is it between choosing `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11`? Should `-std=gnu++11` generally be avoided for portability reasons?

The meaning of `CXX11STD` is to determine the appropriate language standard for C++11 compile. This option exists simply because if *R*'s version of selecting the appropriate C++11 compile option is incorrect for the compiler, you can change it. The reason this exists is because each compiler may define C++11 support slightly differently than the next as indicate in [R Installation and Administration: 2.7.2 C++ Support](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#C_002b_002b-Support):

> It may be [Footnote 13] that there is no suitable flag for C++11 support, in which case a different compiler could be selected for CXX11 and its corresponding flags.

Footnote 13:

> This is true for earlier versions of g++ such as 4.2.1, and also for commonly-used versions of the Solaris compiler CC.

For details on the language standards approved by gcc see [GCC Manual: 3.4 Options Controlling C Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html). Also, for details on using C++11 with *R* in a package see [Writing R Extensions: Section 1.2.4 Using C++11 Code](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code).

Generally, I would avoid explicitly setting this variable. If you must explicitly set this variable, I would recommend going with `-std=c++11` as a majority of compilers support this declaration.

---

> Could the flags for `CXXSTD` and `CXXFLAGS` not just be added to `CXX`, such that the first three lines reduce to `CXX = g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=undefined,address -fno-omit-frame-pointer`. What is the advantage in explicitly specifying `CXXSTD` and `CXXFLAGS`?

Is it possible? Yes. Is it right? No.

Why have *three* variables each with their own goal when we could simply just have one?

The advantages of a *three* variable workflow provide different lines each with a distinct role. This allows for the ability to quickly understand the compilation option. Thus, it is much more straight forward to grok when compared it being crammed into one variable on one line (with terminal width of 80).

e.g.

```
CXX = g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=undefined,address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

vs

```
CXX = g++ 
CXX11STD = -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -fsanitize=undefined,address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

Furthermore, you should opt for `CXX_STD` over `CXXSTD` when packaging as shown in [Writing R Extensions: Section 1.2.4 Using C++11 Code](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code). This is simply to ensure that R registered the package as requiring C++xy. The alternative is to write in the `DESCRIPTION` file the attribute `SystemRequirements: C++xy`, where `xy` denotes the year.

---

> How does `CXX_STD` = `CXX11` work? How is `CXX11` here related to `CXX11` in ~/.R/Makevars?

This sets the compilation and linking for the language to be done with the C++11 compiler set by `CXX11`. By specifying `CXX11`, you are specifying a [variable in `Make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Variables) that will be used to compile the file under the recipe:

```
$(OBJCXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

where `$(OBJCXX)` is `CXX`, `$(ALL_CPPFLAGS)` is given by `$(R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(CLINK_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)`, and `$(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS)` has `$(PKG_OBJCXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(OBJCXXFLAGS)`
.

The above follows [`/R/Makeconf.in`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e73c299909360bf6e99366187726ad8c8fd9f6c3/etc/Makeconf.in#L162). However, the routine may be [`/m4/R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/952684e10c26dfa21e4a8a978a2dc462c2ff07f0/m4/R.m4#L591).

---

> What is the relationship between `CXXFLAGS` and `PKG_CXXFLAGS` (not included in my example)?

Both of these specify the compiler's compilation flags. The order in which they are written in the `Makevars` is different. In particular, we have
[`CXXFLAGS` placed *after* `PKG_CXXFLAGS`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e73c299909360bf6e99366187726ad8c8fd9f6c3/etc/Makeconf.in#L148). **The *right* most option is *always* used.** So, `CXXFLAGS` takes precedence over `PKG_CXXFLAGS`.

There is a brief note on `PKG_*` options in [Writing R Extensions: Section 5.5 Creating shared objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Creating-shared-objects).

### Addendum

The following are questions that were asked by @Dominik in the comment section of this response.

---

> Is it correct that variables defined in `~/.R/Makevars` apply globally to the installation of all packages, while variables in `/src/Makevars` only apply to the present package?

Yes. This is accurate. Variables within `~/.R/Makevars` will apply to all packages while the `/src/Makevars` that ships with each package will only influence settings for that package. The values in `/src/Makevars` will take precedence over `~/.R/Makevars`.

Some packages may ship with `/src/Makevars.win`, which provides a `Makevars` file specifically for the Windows environment.

---

> Is the compilation standard used for a packages nowadays only set via `CXX_STD` and not any more by `PKG_CXXFLAGS` as shown in gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simple-lambda-func-c++11?

There is a slight difference between when these two flags should be used. In particular, `CXX_STD` is only operational in a package environment. Meanwhile, contrary to its name, `PKG_CXXFLAGS`, affects all compile options. Thus, when you quote the above Rcpp gallery post, you are observing a standalone script being run. To quickly engage the correct mode, that requires `PKG_CXXFLAGS` to be set and *not* the `CXX_STD` definition.

Now, forgive me for going on a brief tangent on the history of *standalone use* compilation options.... The use of `PKG_CXXFLAGS` is a bit old school. In fact, the preferred approach in R 3.4 is to set the environment variable `USE_CXX11 = "yes"`. Between R 3.1 and R 3.3, the standard was to set the environment variable `USE_CXX1X = "yes"`. Prior to those instances, the use of `PKG_CXXFLAGS ="-std=c++11"` was preferred. (Except on Windows, which needed `PKG_CXXFLAGS ="-std=c++0x"`.)

---

> Does using `CXX_STD=CXX11` then mean to use all the settings given by `CXX`, `CXXSTD`, `CXXFLAGS` and `CXX11PICFLAGS`?

No. This means to use options set by:

> CXX11 
>   CXX11STD
>   CXX11FLAGS
>   CXX11PICFLAGS

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for this great answer! If you allow, I would have a few follow up questions on this: i) Is it correct that variables defined in `~/.R/Makevars` apply globally to the installation of all packages, while variables in `/src/Makevars` only apply to the present package? ii) Is the compilation standard used for a packages nowaday only set via `CXX_STD` and not any more by `PKG_CXXFALGS` as shown in http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simple-lambda-func-c++11/? iii) Does using `CXX_STD=CXX11` then mean to use all the settings given by `CXX`, `CXXSTD`, `CXXFALGS` and `CXX11PICFLAGS`?

Comment: Again, many thanks for the effort of responding to my additional questions. Note that part (iii) is a bit stupid because I accidentially missed the `11` in the first 3 variables.

Comment: What is `~/.R/Makevars`?? I am on Windows. I am using sourceCpp() to compile a simple model. I want to suppress the -Wreorder warning. Thanks.

Comment: In Windows 10 you can find the `Makevars` file by using `tools::makevars_user()`. I successfully changed the compiler options for `sourceCpp()` by adding `PKG_CXXFLAGS = -Wno-reorder`

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to provide some specific examples for specific systems. I am clueless about c and c++ and just want to get packages that require compilation to compile; in my particular case on a centos system. I currently have the Makevars file as `CC=gcc-7.3.1
CXX=g++7.3.1
CXX_STD=CXX
CXX1X=g++-7.3.1
SHLIB_CXXLD=g++-7.3.1` which gives me errors when I try to compile say Rcpp

Comment: It should just work. This would be better served as a new question or is likely covered already elsewhere.