# Compilation fails when trying to install "pcalg" for R on El Capitan

Tags: r, gfortran, osx-elcapitan

When trying to install the [pcalg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcalg/index.html) package, I am getting the following error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pcalg.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pcalg’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/pcalg’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/54/nwpr9hkn49b1m4h3hjmwph6r0000gn/T/RtmpREqD5T/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("pcalg") :
  installation of package ‘pcalg’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm assuming this is because the `gfortan` package now in `gcc`, but I don't know how to point it to the right place. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Check the makevars file at: ~/.R/Makevars  i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597632/understanding-the-contents-of-the-makevars-file-in-r-macros-variables-r-ma

Comment: This file doesn't exist on my computer