# Installation of custom XGBoost fails due to error in shared library

Tags: r, gcc, installation, xgboost

Im trying to set up a custom version of XGBoost from https://github.com/robjhyndman/M4metalearning in R.

When I run `devtools::install_github("pmontman/customxgboost")` I get this error:

```
> devtools::install_github("pmontman/customxgboost")
Downloading GitHub repo pmontman/customxgboost@master
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/5g/1cypnkxn3fs6tbk5ylfp1rqm0000gn/T/RtmpwXcO18/remotes1ff65ae3da8c/pmontman-customxgboost-ac8dacf/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘xgboost’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
✔  checking vignette meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
─  building ‘xgboost_666.6.4.1.tar.gz’
   Warning: file 'xgboost/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected

* installing *source* package ‘xgboost’ ...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c xgboost_R.cc -o xgboost_R.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c xgboost_custom.cc -o xgboost_custom.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c xgboost_assert.c -o xgboost_assert.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c amalgamation/xgboost-all0.cc -o amalgamation/xgboost-all0.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.cc -o amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c rabit/src/engine_empty.cc -o rabit/src/engine_empty.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c rabit/src/c_api.cc -o rabit/src/c_api.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o xgboost.so ./xgboost_R.o ./xgboost_custom.o ./xgboost_assert.o ./init.o ./amalgamation/xgboost-all0.o ./amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.o ./rabit/src/engine_empty.o ./rabit/src/c_api.o -fopenmp -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/xgboost/libs
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xgboost’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNSt11regex_errorD1Ev
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so
Error: loading failed
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/xgboost’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/xgboost’
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (convertido del aviso) installation of package ‘/var/folders/5g/1cypnkxn3fs6tbk5ylfp1rqm0000gn/T//RtmpwXcO18/file1ff67e4c38d5/xgboost_666.6.4.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Im using

My ~/.R/Makevars file is as follow:

```
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-8
CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-8
CXX11=/usr/local/bin/gcc-8
```

I also tried install the original XGBoost following this guide : 
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

and everything gone well. So the problem is exclusively of R, im a little stuck. Any suggerences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fix the problem, im going to describe the entire process.

In essence you have to follow this steps:

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

Specifically this is important: `brew install gcc@8`

This command download the version of gcc that supports openMP an important library to XGBoost due to the nature of some parallel characteristics.

Maybe the shared library `xgboost.so` fails due to a  "symbol not found error". This occurs when your are trying to link objects compiled from different gcc versions.

More info here: [What does "Symbol not found / Expected in: flat namespace" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006614/what-does-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace-actually-mean)

To fix this I changed the contents of `~/.R/Makevars` file to :

`CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-8
 CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-8
 CXX11=/usr/local/bin/g++-8`

Note CX11 is different from original question version.

This solved my problem.

More info about `Makevars` file here : [Understanding the contents of the Makevars file in R (macros, variables, ~/.R/Makevars and pkg/src/Makevars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597632/understanding-the-contents-of-the-makevars-file-in-r-macros-variables-r-ma)

If the above fails it is recommended to delete the R libraries and reinstall it, there may be a problem with a symbolic link or similar.

R libraries (Mac Os High Sierra) are stored here:

`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/`