# Compile my package with g++-8 and clang++

Tags: c++, r, r-package

I have a package and each time I make an update to the CRAN I check it with `g++-7`, `g++-8`, `clang++` and so on according to the different compilers used on CRAN.

My `Makevars(.win)` is the following

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) -I../inst/include/
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

To change the compiler I change `.R/Makevars` like so:

```
CXX = clang++
```

However `.R/Makevar` is respected only if I removed the `CXX_STD` flag in the package `Makevars`. Otherwise the default applies and it compiles with `g++` (7.4.0 on my computer) and `-std=gnu++11`.

I would like to know if there is a better/good workflow to compile and test my package with several compilers and without modifying the package `Makevars`.

I'm running a Linux system, and I compile with the button <kbd>Clean and rebuild</kbd> from Rstudio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the contents of the Makevars file in R (macros, variables, ~/.R/Makevars and pkg/src/Makevars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597632/understanding-the-contents-of-the-makevars-file-in-r-macros-variables-r-ma). There are also `CXX11` etc., which van be changed in `~/.R/Makevars`.

Comment: This indeed answer my question. I understand that the use of `CXX11` in `~/.R/Makevars` goes with the use of `CXX11` in `src/Makevars`. Thank you.