# How do I find the value of an R compilation variable, as set in Makevars?

Tags: r, makefile

There are [many places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597632) where I might use Makevars or Makeconf to modify or overwrite the value of a variable used to configure compilation options in R.

I'd like to be able to see a list of all variables that are currently set, and their values.

Running `R CMD config --all` lists many, but not all, global values; for instance, `DLLFLAGS` is set in `<R-version-path>/etc/<arch>/Makeconf` but not included in this list.

Neither can I see a way to configure the `config` command to show the settings as they would apply within a given package, which may overwrite certain variables using local `src/Makevars` or `src/Makevars.win` files.